# Select range of lines in Notepad++

Tags: range, selection, notepad++, lines

Is there a way to select range of lines in Notepad++? I would like to write two numbers - from and to, say: from 10000 to 25000.

I've got this large MySQL dump file and I can select it only by using some function.

Comment: [Similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/405522/selecting-range-of-lines-in-notepad) on SuperUser.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Easiest way:

1. <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>, go to line 10,000.

   - **Menu** > <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Begin/End select</kbd>.
2. <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>, go to line 25,000.

   - **Menu** > <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Begin/End select</kbd>.

You now have your range selected.

Or, simply right click for "Begin/End select" option.

Comment: This works like a charm!

Answer (score 17):

I was trying to figure the same thing out FOREVER! I finally figured it out. The closest answer I could get was <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PageUp</kbd>.

But if you want to select more and not the whole page do go to the last line your wanting and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>. That will select from where you are to top of your text. The same goes for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>End</kbd> will select from what line you are at to the last line.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know Notepad++, but as a quick solution, you can use

```
perl -ne 'print if $. >= 10_000 && $. <= 25_000' < file.sql > some-lines.sql
```

(The _ in numbers in Perl are just for legibility and can be omitted. It's like writing 10,000 in the US or 10.000 in Germany, but without the cultural confusion.)

Answer (score 0):

put your cursor at the start of line 10000 then press and hold the `shift` key use the scroll bar to go to line 25000 and `Right click` at the end of it, this will select all the lines between 10000 and 25000, also while pressing and holding the `shift` key you can hold and drag the `Right click` to change selection area

Comment: this is faster you dont have to go to menu > edit > Begin/End select twice with this one you just hold shift try it..

Comment: I'm not sure it is quicker to scroll 15000 lines.