# Select range of lines in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am looking to select lines from line number 1000 to line number 1997 and after delete them. I am using notepad++ and I am looking to do so, so after I can delete them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select range of lines in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490968/select-range-of-lines-in-notepad)

Comment: Worked a treat for splitting a huge csv file into million row chunks for Excel

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Easiest way for big files:

1. <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>, go to line 1000.

   - **Menu** > <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Begin/End select</kbd>.
2. <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>, go to line 1997.

   - **Menu** > <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Begin/End select</kbd>.

You now have your range selected with few clicks and no scroll.

Comment: There is no Begin/End select in the Edit Menu, probably an older verions

Comment: @Dexters, I've just checked with the latest release (v6.6.9) and the option is there: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2rfczg4.jpg

Comment: you can right click at the line you want to start, select 'begin/end select'.  Scroll to the line you want to end, right click, select 'begin/end select'.  All lines in between will be highlighted.

Answer (score 15):

Try Menu => **Search** => **Goto** and enter the first line number. Next use Menu => **Edit** => **Begin/End select**. Then **Goto** the second line number and repeat the **Begin/End select**. Finally delete the selected area.

Answer (score 13):

Place cursor on line 1000, scroll to line 1997 using the mouse / scroll bar.

Press and hold the `shift` key and then click on line 1997. This will select all the lines in between and you can then delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Select the range and **`Shift +Alt`**  and **`Down`**  go down till you need. you can extend in between using by pressing right/left arrow